# Update a record in a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a table A(:name, :flag) and want to update the flag column of a record in the table if a certain condition evaluates to true.

```
if A.find(300).flag == false
 //Will this work -> A.find(300).flag = true
```

What should I write in that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if A.find(300).flag == false
 //Will this work -> A.find(300).flag = true
```

change to

```
A.find(300).update(flag: true) if A.find(300).flag == false
```

You can add method to  a.rb

```
def self.update_if_false id
  find(id).update(flasg: true) if A.find(id).flag == false
end
```

Then you can use it as `A.update_if_false(300)`

Comment: Will I need to write anything in the A.rb file like a method like "def update" ?

Comment: You dont need to use i`f A.find(300).falg == false`. It is now in method, just pass your record `id` ( example 300) ad it will update `flag to true if it is false`

Comment: Doing it in model will be a bad implementation, I think.

Comment: Then use what I have suggested, line as change. You do not have to create update method it is already in model if you use `ActiveRecord`

Comment: if A.find(300).flag == false
   A.find(300).update(flag: true)
else
   //something
end
Is this OK?

Answer (score 0):

This will decrease database call if flag is true:

Rails 4:

```
obj = A.find(300)
obj.update(flag: true) unless obj.flag
```

Rails 3.2:

```
obj = A.find(300)
obj.update_attributes(flag: true) unless obj.flag
```

*Note: `update` method made public and aliased with update_attributes in active record 4.*

Answer (score 0):

yes..it will work...i tried in ruby2.0 console..**Assuming** you have all the attributes present....

```
2.0.0-p481 :026 >  Image.find(30).title = true
Image Load (7.8ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 30]]
 => true
```

you can go ahead and add your update statement ..if true else false.

```
if A.find(300).flag == false
  ##do something
else
  ##do other thing
end
```